# Need to format date in SQL from string using charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I am trying to format a date in mm/dd/yyyy from string data using charindex, the date in the string is yyyymmdd. I have tried using convert, cast, castconvert.

If anyone could help that would be great! I have sample code

```
CONVERT (
                       VARCHAR (10)
                     , CASE
                           WHEN CHARINDEX ('^3507=', reg.BetaRequestString) = 0 THEN
                               ''
                           ELSE
                               RIGHT(LEFT(reg.BetaRequestString, CHARINDEX ('^3507=', reg.BetaRequestString) + 13), 8)
                       END
                     , 101
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data? It's not clear which format you are converting from and which one you are converting to

Comment: Store the dates in Datetime columns. Suddenly this becomes very easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a nvarchar(10)
set @a='20180203'
select 
convert(nvarchar(10),substring(@a,5,2)+'/'+substring(@a,7,2)+'/'
+substring(@a,1,4),101)
```

Comment: will this still work if I dont know the date itself the format in the string is always the same

Comment: While this code-only answer might answer the question, please add an explanation of why it does so. This will help future users evaluate the answer for their situation.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want this:

```
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX ('^3507=', reg.BetaRequestString) = 0 
     THEN ''
     ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),RIGHT(LEFT(reg.BetaRequestString, CHARINDEX ('^3507=', reg.BetaRequestString) + 13), 8), 101)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

When you know your input date format , you can split the parts and reorganise the date.

```
declare @date varchar(100)='20021230' , 
 @Year int,@month int ,@day int

select @year=Substring(@date,1,4) ,@month=SUBSTRING(@date,5,2),@day=SUBSTRING(@date,7,2)

select convert(VARCHAR(10),(DATEFROMPARTS(@year,@month,@day)),101)
```

> output-12/30/2002

Comment: will this still work if I dont know the date itself the format in the string is always the same

Comment: Yes it will work ... is your date stored in a table column ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use datetime style in convert function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles

```
DECLARE @yyyymmdd sysname = '20180101'
SELECT CONVERT(sysname, CONVERT(datetime, @yyyymmdd, 112), 101)
```